# Tracking browser history with Angular

Tags: angular

I'm having difficulty finding how I can access the browsers URL history with Angular. In AngularJS, `$location` had stuff, and while the Angular `Location` service has forward and back, I don't see any way to see the history or go back a certain number of steps. Is there a service I'm missing?

If not, I could build my own History Service, but I also can't find an Observable or something similar that updates when a new URL is hit in the browser. Any advice?

Comment: Going back *n* steps is just `history.back(n)`. You can't see the history because Angular uses the browser history mechanism, which for security reasons does not expose the details of the history. For an observable of URLs, use [`activatedRoute.url`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#activated-route). However, I would recommend against trying to override/"improve" on the build-in history mechanism. You are likely to end up confusing both the user and yourself..

Comment: `history` as in an angular service, or the default JS `window.history` object? And actually, I realized `activatedRoute.url` is what I want, because I don't actually want to go back, but rather use previous hit URLs to determine the next location to send the user to. If you put this as the answer, I'd accept it, as it's both a great explanation and provides me my results :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a hashMap to save all my data and restore it on persons return. And that's the only thing that worked for me.

If you do this though please don't forget to clear data when logging out or after certain time. Just just saying out there for people who use this, "use Location from @angular/core" Typescript IDE's don't import it by default.

Hope this helps if it's a immediate request. But I would really like to see if someone has a solution.